# How do I use LAST_INSERT_ID in a single query one-to-many relationship?

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I have two tables, *questions* and *answers*.
answers contains a key *question_id*

When I create a question, I insert one record to the *questions* table and several records into the *answers* table. Is it possible to use LAST_INSERT_ID() or similar to do all this in one query?

I.e. something like

```
INSERT INTO questions VALUES(NULL, 'My question');

INSERT INTO answers VALUES(NULL, LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'Answer 1');
INSERT INTO answers VALUES(NULL, LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'Answer 2');
INSERT INTO answers VALUES(NULL, LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'Answer 3');
```

Obviously, this query wouldn't work since LAST_INSERT_ID() changes after every statement. Is there anyway to make this work or will I have to break this up into two queries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use bulk inserts like this :

```
INSERT INTO answers VALUES
          (NULL, LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'Answer 1') , 
          (NULL, LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'Answer 2') , 
          (NULL, LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'Answer 3');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to store de value into a variable

```
INSERT INTO questions VALUES(NULL, 'My question');
SET @id = (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());
INSERT INTO answers VALUES(NULL, @id, 'Answer 1');
INSERT INTO answers VALUES(NULL, @id, 'Answer 2');
INSERT INTO answers VALUES(NULL, @id, 'Answer 3');
```

I think there is another way to do it but maybe it will give you an idea.

Comment: While this maybe works, Sabeens anwer is clearly what I was looking for.

Comment: Yes... is the best option. I didn't know we could use bulk inserts with LAST_INSERT_ID. :D